# Connecting MS SQL to CKAN

Tags: ckan

I am trying to fetch the MSSQl Database Data into CKAN
is it possible to integrate or connection to MSSQL?
any extension needed for that?
if yes can you brief me about the procedure for that?

Thanks in Advance 
sai kumar!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can fetch data from MSSQL. Check this example for more info [MSSQL](https://github.com/keitaroinc/ckanext-knowledgehub/blob/master/ckanext/knowledgehub/backend/mssql.py)